# Microsoft Teams task module with URL not working

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams

Tring to trigger a task module that will display a web page.
All I was able to get is an empty Task Module with the title, while the specified height and width do not affect nor is the URL displayed.

[image: Displayed Task Module]

The task module fetch handler function:

```js
const { TeamsActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
class Foo extends TeamsActivityHandler {
/* ... */
  handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context, data) {
    return {
      task: {
        type: 'continue',
        value: {
          title: 'Task module title',
          height: 1000,
          width: 700,
          fallbackUrl: 'https://giltichon.com/bar',
          url: 'https://giltichon.com/bar',
        }
      }
    };
  };
};
```

I've made sure to list the URL in the apps manifest `validDomains` but still the URL is a no show...

UPDATE: also added `composeExtensions` property

App manifest:

```json
{
...
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "***",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [],
      "messageHandlers": [
        {
          "type": "link",
          "value": {
            "domains": [
              "giltichon.com"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "validDomains": [
    "giltichon.com"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the page not showing, its almost certainly a domain validity issue. It's always worth checking the format of your domains (you just need 'www.contoso.com', not 'https://www.contoso.com'), but in this case, because you have are using a task module, there will be a 'composeExtension' section in your manifest. This has its own "valid domain's" section, in the following format:

"messageHandlers": [
{
"type": "link",
"value": {
"domains": [
"whatever.azurewebsites.net"
]
}
}
]
It looks like you might be missing this additional domain value.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the `manifest.json` file, I've added the `composeExtension` property but no help... :\

Comment: I assume you're not REALLY pointing to Google.com. Is it an internal website in reality? If so, does it include the Teams JS SDK? I think that's also a requirement (it is for a Tab to show properly, I can't now for a Task Module). If it *is* a requirement and you can't change the underlying system, you can wrap it in an iframe...

Comment: For the purpose of this question, I've created https://giltichon.com/bar, it's the same HTML page from the [example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module/pages/YouTube.html) question edited

Comment: Ok perfect. Notice how the example has a container frame, which references the MicrosoftTeams.min.js, and then iframes YouTube into that. Please try something similar and see if it works

Comment: Linking the URL to that page does not help

Comment: Not sure what you mean? What exactly are you trying?

Comment: The code in the question is updated with my attempt, the task module still pops up empty

Comment: Is there no subdomain on giltichon.com? like "www" or "app" or whatever?

Comment: ok I see it. I'm not sure if the Task Module docs cover this, but as per the Tabs docs, I think you need to reference the Teams JS SDK for it to render properly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs specifically "...you need to add the Teams JavaScript client SDK to your page, and call microsoftTeams.initialize() after your page loads. Doing so will tell Teams to display your page..."

Comment: @ZimGil Hi are you already solved this issue?

Comment: I have not, but I am no longer working on that project.